# read() fails with Bad address, valgrind shows Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)

Tags: c, linux, realloc

I have a function to read a file using the `read()` system call and return a `char` pointer with the data read from the file. The function reallocates space if necessary. After a specific point the read fails with the error "Bad Address". The minimum code which fails is show below:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const unsigned BUFSIZE = 8192;

typedef struct
{
    char* buffer;
    long size;
} string_t;

string_t read_file(const char* path)
{
    string_t error = { .buffer = NULL, .size = -1 };
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open() failed in read_file");
        return error;
    }

    string_t s;
    s.buffer = malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof(char));
    s.size = 0;

    int nread = 0;
    long total_read = 0;

    while ((nread = read(fd, s.buffer + total_read, BUFSIZE)) != 0) {
        if (nread == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                perror("error EINTR");
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("read() failed in read_file");
                close(fd);
                return error;
            }
        } else {
            printf("%ld %ld %d\n", total_read, s.size, nread);
            total_read += nread;
            s.size = total_read;
            if (nread == BUFSIZE) {
                if (realloc(s.buffer, s.size + BUFSIZE) == NULL) {
                    perror("out of memory...");
                    close(fd);
                    return error;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    close(fd);
    s.buffer[s.size] = 0;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    const char* path = "/usr/share/dict/cracklib-small";

    string_t s = read_file(path);
    if (s.size == -1) {
        printf("error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", s.buffer);
    free(s.buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives the following:

```
0 0 8192
8192 8192 8192
16384 16384 8192
24576 24576 8192
32768 32768 8192
40960 40960 8192
49152 49152 8192
57344 57344 8192
65536 65536 8192
73728 73728 8192
81920 81920 8192
90112 90112 8192
98304 98304 8192
106496 106496 8192
114688 114688 8192
122880 122880 8192
131072 131072 8192
read() failed in read_file: Bad address
error
```

Valgrind shows:

```
==4299== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==4299==    at 0x5184F00: __read_nocancel (in /usr/lib/libc-2.21.so)
==4299==    by 0x400A58: read_file (file_helpers.c:31)
==4299==    by 0x400AA3: main (file_helpers.c:64)
==4299==  Address 0x7568040 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8,192 free'd
==4299==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4299==    by 0x400A12: read_file (file_helpers.c:46)
==4299==    by 0x400AA3: main (file_helpers.c:64)
==4299==
```

I can see it complains about the realloc but I do not understand what is causing the bad address error. Is the buffer to which `read()` writes getting corrupt somehow after the last `realloc()`?

`wc -c` reports the file on which the function is run to have 477238 bytes.

Comment: Thank you. This question can be used as an example for "How to write a Good Question".

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use [`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) to determine the file size, allocate the space, and then read it all at once?

Comment: I was writing a crawler as a side project and wanted to see how reading from a socket worked without knowing the size of the response  so I thought I would try out reading from a file first.

Comment: a few notes:  1) the expression 'sizeof(char)' always returns 1 and has no effect on the call to malloc().  It just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression from any calls to malloc()  2) the call to read() is always asking for BUF_SIZE bytes, but after any bytes are read, there is not BUF_SIZE bytes available in the input buffer.  Suggest using: 'while ((nread = read(fd, s.buffer + total_read, BUFSIZE-total_read)) != 0) {'

Comment: a few notes, continued 3) passing a complete struct is not a good idea, for several reasons.  Suggest passing/returning pointer to struct.  4) after a successful call to malloc() then on an error, the pointer to the allocated memory needs to be passed to free().  5) the call to realloc() did not save the pointer returned from realloc().  The result is the s.buffer is still pointing to the old allocated memory, which was free'd after the allocated memory was copied to the new allocated memory.

Comment: a few notes, continued: 6) regarding this line: 'if (realloc(s.buffer, s.size + BUFSIZE) == NULL) {'  and following code block, it should be 'if (char * temp = realloc(s.buffer, s.size + BUFSIZE) == NULL) { ..... else {s.buffer = temp;}'  7) to avoid text replacement errors, when #define'ing a numeric value, always surround the numeric value with parens

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Always enable all warnings when compiling.   then fix the warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use, '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

Comment: when calling malloc(), always check (!= NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of `realloc()` looks wrong at first sight.

```
if (realloc(s.buffer, s.size + BUFSIZE) == NULL)
```

This statement checks if `realloc()` is successfuil or not. If failure, this handles the case. Fine.

What if `realloc()` is successful?

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc),

> The `realloc()` function **returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory**, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable and **may be different from `ptr`**, or NULL if the request fails. If `size` was equal to `0`, either `NULL` or a pointer suitable to be passed to `free()` is returned. If `realloc()` fails the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.

That means, you're losing the newly allocated memory, and using the `free()`d memory afterwards.

I guess, you'd have expected that `realloc()` will resize the `s.buffer` itself, but, I'm afraid, that is not the case here.

**Solution**:

You should collect the return value of `realloc()` in a temporary variable, check against `NULL`, and if not `NULL`, assign the same back to the pointer `s.buffer`.

FWIW, **don't** use the original pointer itself to collect the return value of `realloc()`, in case if it fails, you'll lose the actual memory also.

Comment: fails to address the problem with the read() being able to input characters past the end of the allocated memory input buffer.

Answer (score 4):

The issue might be with how you are using `realloc`.  `realloc(s.buffer, s.size + BUFSIZE) == NULL` is not the correct way to use `realloc`.  The return value of `realloc` taken from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html) is:

> Upon successful completion with a size not equal to 0, realloc() shall
>   return a pointer to the (**possibly moved**) allocated space. If size is
>   0, either a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be successfully
>   passed to free() shall be returned. If there is not enough available
>   memory, realloc() shall return a null pointer and
>   set errno to ENOMEM.

The key part is the fact that `realloc` can move the allocated space and its data.  So you cannot just check whether the return value is NULL.  You want to do something more along the lines of:

```
void *tmp = realloc(s.buffer, s.size + BUFSIZE);
if (tmp == NULL) {
  perror("out of memory...");
  free(s.buffer);  // Release the memory to avoid a leak
  close(fd);
  return error;
}
s.buffer = tmp;
```

In other words update the pointer with the return value of `realloc`.  If the data was not moved, `realloc` returns the memory addressed passed into it; if it was moved, `realloc` will return a new address.

Update:

Another issue that you probably aren't experiencing is how you handle the return value of `read`.  If `read` returned less than was requested than you won't `realloc` more memory and further reads might read past the buffer.  You might not experiencing this right now as it will only show if `read` doesn't fail and doesn't read less than the requested amount of data.  A solution, which includes the `realloc` fix is below:

```
int nread = 0;
long total_read = 0;
int space_remaining = BUFSIZE;

while ((nread = read(fd, s.buffer + total_read, space_remaining)) != 0) {
        if (nread == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                perror("error EINTR");
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("read() failed in read_file");
                close(fd);
                return error;
            }
        } else {
            printf("%ld %ld %d\n", total_read, s.size, nread);
            total_read += nread;
            s.size = total_read;
            space_remaining -= nread;
            if (space_remaining == 0) {
                void *tmp = realloc(s.buffer, s.size + BUFSIZE);
                if (tmp == NULL) {
                    perror("out of memory...");
                    free(s.buffer);  // Release the memory to avoid a leak
                    close(fd);
                    return error;
                }
                s.buffer = tmp;
                space_remaining = BUFSIZE;
            }
        }
    }
```

The variable `space_remaining` is used to keep track how much space is left in the buffer.  This is the amount read and is reset when the buffer's size is increased.  Since you are `realloc`-ing more space you do not want to do the typical `(BUFSIZE-total_read)` pattern that has previously been suggested, although this is the typical pattern one sees.

Again you won't see this problem if `read` always returns the requested amount of data.

Comment: fails to address the problem with the read() being able to input characters past the end of the allocated memory input buffer.

Comment: @user3629249 the author is always reallocing to add additional space so does not need to do (BUFSIZE-total_read), I thought that was a mistake the first time I read it write has this is the typical pattern you see but it is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @user3629249 actually after looking over the question code, we are both wrong as the realloc is not always happening after every read.  Updating answer.